# Enviar 2 arrays por a ajax a php y 2 variables

Tags: ajax, array

Necesito actualizar múltiples registros en una tabla productos que posee los campos `id_producto` y `stock_actual`.

Le paso los array `codigo` y `total` por ajax y no me funciona, también envío 2 variables para otra actualización. El array `codigo` serían los `id` de cada valor del array total que debe actualizar el campo `stock_actual` con sus valores.

Adjunto el **script** y el archivo **php**, Gracias.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function generar() {
  var idproducto = document.getElementById("id-producto").value;
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("canti").value;
  var total =[]; // array?

 var codigo =[]; // array?

  $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
    total.push($(tr).find('td:eq(6)').text());
    codigo.push($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text());

    });




 var totala = total;
  var codigoa = codigo;






var dataString = {idproducto:idproducto,
                  cantidad:cantidad,
                  totala:totala,
                  codigoa:codigoa}


      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "data/ejecutaentc.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
         success: function(response){
        alertify.alert("Atención","Cantidad agregada: "+totala);
        }
  });


}
    </script>
```

//archivo php donde van los datos de ajax

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
require_once "conexion.php";

$idproducto = $_POST['idproducto'];

$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$total = $_POST['totala'];

//$foo = array($total);

$codigo = $_POST['codigoa'];
//$codigo = json_decode($_POST['codigo']);
//$fooc = array($codigo);
//var_dump($codigo);
var_dump($_POST['codigoa']);
$icodigo = count($codigo);
$itotal = count($total);

for ($i = 0; $i < $icodigo && $i < $itotal; $i++) {

    $sentencia1 = "UPDATE productos SET stock_actual ='$total' where id_producto= '$codigo'";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia1);

}

$sentencia2 = "UPDATE productos SET stock_actual = stock_actual+'$cantidad' where id_producto= '$idproducto'";

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sentencia2);

?>
```

// agrego imagen de la tabla de donde extraigo los datos y el input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//parte del codigo html desde el boton Generar entrada

```
<?php

extract($_GET);

$sql = "SELECT productos.id_producto, productos.name, productos.marca, productos.modelo,  productos.stock_actual,  productos.precio_compra, productos.precio_unidad,  categorias.name, media.file_name, productos.fecha_ingreso, productos.proveedor,  productos.nro_expediente,   productos.desc_prod, productos.id_categoria, productos.id_media FROM productos, categorias, media WHERE productos.id_producto = '$id' and productos.id_categoria= categorias.id_categoria and productos.id_media= media.id_media";

$ressql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($ressql)) {
    $id = $row[0];
    $name = $row[1];
    $marca = $row[2];
    $modelo = $row[3];
    $stock_actual = $row[4];

    $precio_compra = $row[5];
    $precio_unidad = $row[6];
    $id_categoria = $row[7];
    $id_media = $row[8];
    $fecha_ingreso = date_create($row[9]);
    $proveedor = $row[10];
    $nro_expediente = $row[11];
    $desc_prod = $row[12];
    $id_cat1 = $row[13];
    $id_med1 = $row[14];
}

?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-title">
          <div>
            <h1><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>Entrada de Productos Compuestos</h1>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-9 ">
            <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 390px">
              <div class="card-title-w-btn">
                <h3 class="title">Detalle de Producto</h3>

              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <form method="post" action="data/ejecutaent.php">

                <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">IDarea:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-area" id="id-area" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id_area)) {
    echo $id_area;
}
?>"  readonly>
               </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">IDusuario:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-user" id="id-user" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id_user)) {
    echo $id_user;
}
?>"  readonly>
               </div>


                <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
                <label class="control-label">ID:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="id-producto" id="id-producto" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($id)) {
    echo $id;
}
?>"  readonly>
               </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <label class="control-label">Nombre:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-name" id="product-name" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($name)) {
    echo $name;
}
?>"  readonly>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Marca:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-marca" id="product-marca" placeholder="Marca" value="<?php if (isset($marca)) {
    echo $marca;
}
?>"  readonly>
               </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <label class="control-label">Modelo:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="product-modelo" id="product-modelo" placeholder="Modelo" value="<?php if (isset($modelo)) {
    echo $modelo;
}
?>"  readonly>
               </div>



                <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Proveedor:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="15" name="proveedor" id="proveedor" placeholder="Proveedor" value="<?php if (isset($proveedor)) {
    echo $proveedor;
}
?>" readonly >
               </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                 <label class="control-label">Nº de Expediente</label>
                 <input type="text" maxlength="14"class="form-control" name="expediente" id="expediente" placeholder="Expediente" value="<?php if (isset($nro_expediente)) {
    echo $nro_expediente;
}
?>" readonly >
               </div>


               <div class="col-md-4">

                  <label class="control-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                  <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local"      class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fechain" id="fechain" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="<?php echo $fecha_ingreso->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') ?>"  readonly>

              </div>


              <div class="col-md-4">

                  <label class="control-label">Fecha de Entrada</label>
                  <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local"      class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fecha-in" id="fecha-in" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="<?php echo $hoy3->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') ?>"readonly>

              </div>




                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Cantidad en depósito:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">

                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
                   <input type="number"  min="1" max="99999999" step="0.001" class="form-control" name="cantidad_ini" id="cantidad_ini" placeholder="Cantidad" value="<?php if (isset($stock_actual)) {
    echo $stock_actual;
}
?>" readonly>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Cantidad ingresada:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">

                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-archive"></i></span>
                   <input type="number"   min="0.00" max="99999999" step="0.001" class="form-control" name="cantidad_ent" id="cantidad_ent" placeholder="Cantidad" value="" >
                  </div>
                </div>

         <div class="col-md-4" style="display: none;" >
                    <label class="control-label">Precio x Unidad:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">

                   <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                   <input type="number"  max="99999" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="precio_unidad" id="precio_unidad" placeholder="Precio x unidad" value="<?php if (isset($precio_unidad)) {echo $precio_unidad;}?>">
                  </div>
                </div>


        <div class="col-md-4" style="display: none;" >
                    <label class="control-label">Precio total:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">

                   <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                   <input type="number"  max="9999999999" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="precio_compra" id="precio_compra" placeholder="Precio total" value="<?php if (isset($precio_compra)) {echo $precio_compra;}?>">
                  </div>
                </div>



                 <div class="col-md-4 ">
                 <label class="control-label">Nº de Remito</label>
                 <input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9--]/g,'');"  maxlength="15" class="form-control" name="remito" id="remito" placeholder="Remito" value="<?php echo '0000' . '-' . $id ?>" required readonly >
               </div>


               <div class="col-md-4 ">
                 <label class="control-label">Receptor:</label>
                 <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="receptor-ent" id="receptor-ent" placeholder="Receptor" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>" required readonly>
               </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                 <label class="control-label">Observaciones:</label>
                 <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="obs_ent" id="obs_ent" placeholder="Oservación" value="" >
               </div>
                <h2></h2>

                <div class="col-md-10" >

                    <h2></h2>

                   <a  href="adm_prodc.php" id="vlistado" name="vlistado" class="btn btn-info">Volver al Listado</a>
                   <button  type="button" onclick="abreModal()"class="btn btn-info"   > <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; Detalle de productos</button>

          <button type="button" onclick="generar()" value="Generar producto" id="add_prod" name="add_prod" class="btn btn-info" ><i class="fas fa-print"></i> Generar Entrada</button>
                    </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


                   <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card" style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 390px">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Imagen </h3>
                  <p><img src='<?php echo "uploads/$id_media" ?>' class='img-thumbnail'></p>
                </div>
              </div>

              </div>
                </div>

    <div id="resultados1" class="table-container"  style="display:none; "><!-- Carga los datos ajax

             Modal Busca Producto-->


        <h4>Detalle de productos que integran el <?php echo $name ?> </h4>
        <h2></h2>
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <label >Cantidad ingresada:</label>
         <input name="canti" id="canti" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(1, this.maxLength);"
        type = "number"
        maxlength = "4"
        min="1">
       </div>
       <h3></h3>
       <button  type="button"  id="calculo" name="calculo" onclick="asignar()"class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top: 25px;"  > <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>&nbsp; Asignar cantidad</button>
    <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>
    <style>
     .table-container {
        height: 30em;
    }
    table {
      table-layout: fixed;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    table thead {
        /* head takes the height it requires,
        and it's not scaled when table is resized */
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: calc(100% - 0.9em);
    }
    table tbody {
        /* body takes all the remaining available space */
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: block;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    table tbody tr {
        width: 100%;
    }
    table thead,
    table tbody tr {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    /* decorations */
    .table-container {
        /*border: 1px solid black;*/
        padding: 0.3em;
        min-width: 100%;

    }
    .codigo {
      width: 10%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .producto {
      width: 15%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .modelo {
      width: 15%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .expediente {
      width: 20%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .stock {
      width: 15%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .cantidad {
      width: 15%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .total {
      width: 15%;

      text-align: center;


    }
    .red{
        background: #654DAF  !important;
        color: #fff;
      }
    table {
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }
    table td, table th {
        padding: 0.3em;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    table th {
        border: 1px solid grey;
    }
    </style>




                                          <?php
    require_once 'data/conexion.php';

    $sql = "SELECT producto_comp.id_producto as idcomp, productos.name as name, productos.modelo as modelo,  productos.nro_expediente as expediente, productos.stock_actual as stockactual, producto_comp.cantidad_producto as cantidad  from producto_comp, productos where  producto_comp.codigopc = '$id' and  productos.id_producto = producto_comp.id_producto  and producto_comp.id_area = '$id_area' and producto_comp.codigopc NOT IN (0) order by productos.name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    ?>

                                            <table  class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0"
                                               >
                                             <thead>


                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="codigo" >Código</th>

                                                <th class="producto">Producto</th>
                                                <th class="modelo">Modelo</th>
                                                <th class="expediente" >Expediente</th>

                                                <th  class="stock"> Stock actual </th>
                                                <th class="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
                                                <th class="total">Stock restante</th>

                                            </tr>

                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?> <tr><?php
    $codigo = $row['idcomp'];
        $producto = $row['name'];
        $modelo = $row['modelo'];
        $expediente = $row['expediente'];
        $stock = $row['stockactual'];
        $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];

        ?>

                                                <td class='codigo' ><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
                                                <td class="producto" ><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
                                                <td class="modelo" ><?php echo $modelo; ?></td>
                                                <td class="expediente"><?php echo $expediente; ?></td>
                                                <td class="stock"  ><?php echo $stock; ?></td>
                                                  <td class="cantidad"><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
                                                   <td class="total" ></td>



         </tr>
         <?php
    }
    ?>
     </tbody>
     <tfoot>
       <tr>
         <th></th>
       </tr>


     </tfoot>



     </table>


     </div>


        </div>




      </body>

<?php

require_once 'static/footer.php'

?>
```

// agrego una imagen de como muestra el array totala en success: //function(response){
  //      alertify.alert("Atención","Cantidad agregada: "+totala);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si perdon es que estoy desesperado y nadie más observo mi pregunta y lo habia editado pero no me actualiza la Sentencia 1 , no se como probar los datos del array que estan llegando al archivo php. Con un echo como seria?

Comment: Perdon no pude resolver con mi pregunta anterior el problema y reedite el codigo pero no tuve más respuestas

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Depuraste los datos que estás recibiendo en PHP? ¿Qué recibes, cómo lo recibes, cuál es el error o dificultad? Haz un **`var_dump($_POST);`** y dinos qué muestra. Tienes que depurar los datos y te ahorrarás horas.

Comment: Perdon Como lo depuro ??

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99696/discussion-on-question-by-julio-enviar-2-arrays-por-a-ajax-a-php-y-2-variables).